# React can not POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have using a payment service.And this service posts a token to a react page.But the page showing CAN NOT POST error.
[image]

Posted url is Callbackurl.The service posts the token correctly.There is no problem here.

And this is my react code of the requested url:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../../store/reducer";
import { bindActionCreators, Dispatch } from "redux";
import { History } from "history";

interface OwnProps {
  history: History<any>;
}

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    language: state.system.language,
    systemUserInfo: state.system.userInfo,
    formData: state.form.formData,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch) {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators(
      {
      },
      dispatch
    ),
  };
}

type HomeProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
  ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps> & OwnProps;

class Pay extends React.Component<HomeProps> {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mt-5">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 mt-5">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-body">Ödeme İşlemi Onaylandı.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Pay);
```

And this is the error:

[image]

Comment: The status code is `404 Not found`, because the page cannot be found. In your React app, do you have a route `/payment/success` and do you start your React app on port `3000`?

Comment: Well. As the error message says, you can't make a POST request to the React dev server. It isn't clear why you are trying to. If the API you are using requires an HTTP server to make a POST callback to, then you can't use the React dev server for it.

Comment: @Kapobajza — The React dev server cannot have POST routes at all.

Comment: @Kapobajza Yes it is running on port 3000.And also I can access the page with its url.My payment service tries to post a token to this page,so ı will be able to check that payment is done or not.But ı am getting this error.

Comment: You can not transfer the data between pages via POST request in React application(running on web servers). This could be done in some scenarios when developing server side applications (eg. .NET with MVC), but in React this is not an option. Global state management (eg Redux or Context API) serves this purpose, when you want to share some data between multiple pages. Simply dispatch data in global state, then navigate to target page, and on target page you can access data from the global state.

Comment: @MilosPavlovic my api is created with .NET.I am tryin to post data with a backend service.

Comment: @Fatih what is the mechanism for sending messages from API to React client, are you using something like SignalR?